# How can show wizard call from python code?

Tags: odoo, wizard, odoo-13

I want to show a wizard, I try with this, but it does not show the wizard.

Someone can help me.

```
if self.move_id:
   view = self.env.ref('modified_pos.pos_assign_manual_quants_form_view')
   wiz = self.env['pos.assign.manual.quants']
   return {
      'name': _('Change quantity'),
      'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
      'view_type': 'form',
      'view_mode': 'form',
      'res_model': 'pos.assign.manual.quants',
      'views': [(view.id, 'form')],
      'view_id': view.id,
      'target': 'new',
      'res_id': wiz.id,
      'context': self.env.context,
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a specific record please pass the '*res_id*' correctly, here you are trying to open a **specific record** but for id, you are passing nothing.

If you want to create a new record on the fly with specific values please use:-

```
wiz = self.env['pos.assign.manual.quants'].create({field:value,...})
```

Or remove *res_id* completely.